# Add text boxes data to grid temporarily using knockout.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Html code

```
<label class="control-label">Contact Person</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Contact name" data-bind="value: ContactPerson" data-validate='{"required":"true"}'><br />

<label class="control-label">ContactNo</label>
<input class="form-control" type="tel" data-bind="value: ContactNo" placeholder="ContactNo" data-validate='{"required":"true"}'><br />

<label class="control-label">E-Mail</label>
<input class="form-control" type="email" data-bind="value: Email" placeholder="Email" data-validate='{"required":"true","email":"true"}'><br />

<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="listTable">
     <thead>
          <tr>
               <th>ContactPerson</th>
               <th>ContactNo</th>
               <th>Email</th>
               <th></th>
          </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody data-bind="template:{name: 'Process-list', 
                                foreach: rootViewModel.BodyContent.ProcessList }">
     </tbody>
</table>
```

when I click  on add button  the data in the three text box should bind to grid ,
and when i click on delete button  of row in grid it should disappear for this i need viewmodel.

Thanks

Comment: Do you already have some viewmodel code? You can add that to the question as well, might make it easier for you to understand if we modify that than if we give you a viewmodel written from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick view model that does the requirements. I selected `ContactNo` as the primary key since they're supposed to be unique. You can use ids if needed instead. It would also be a good idea to run your validations before `add` method is called.

```js
var viewModel = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.ContactPerson = ko.observable();
  self.ContactNo = ko.observable();
  self.Email = ko.observable();
  self.ProcessList = ko.observableArray();
  self.add = function(){
    self.ProcessList.push({
      ContactPerson: self.ContactPerson(),
      ContactNo: self.ContactNo(),
      Email: self.Email(),
    });
    self.ContactPerson('');
    self.ContactNo('');
    self.Email('');
  };
  self.delete = function(data, event){
    self.ProcessList.remove(function(listObject){
      return listObject.ContactNo === data.ContactNo;
    });
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<label class="control-label">Contact Person</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Contact name" data-bind="value: ContactPerson" data-validate='{"required":"true"}'><br />

<label class="control-label">ContactNo</label>
<input class="form-control" type="tel" data-bind="value: ContactNo" placeholder="ContactNo" data-validate='{"required":"true"}'><br />

<label class="control-label">E-Mail</label>
<input class="form-control" type="email" data-bind="value: Email" placeholder="Email" data-validate='{"required":"true","email":"true"}'><br />


<button data-bind="click: add">Add Data</button>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="listTable">
     <thead>
          <tr>
               <th>ContactPerson</th>
               <th>ContactNo</th>
               <th>Email</th>
               <th></th>
          </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody data-bind="template:{name: 'Process-list', 
                                foreach: ProcessList }">
          </tbody>
     </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/html" id="Process-list">
  <tr>  
    <td data-bind="text: ContactPerson"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: ContactNo"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: Email"></td>
    <td><button data-bind="click: $root.delete">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</script>
```